# exactly what does the statement handle(hstmt) do? in ODBC

Tags: sql, c, odbc

I`m new to write c code for ODBC 
but here I have question...
after searching for the tutorial for odbc function tutorials for C, I still caanot get exactly
how they work collaborately...

what does the statement handle hstmt exactly do for database data?
I knew it controls the SQL query statements that I give as a parameter. but,,
then every SQL statements that i give as query should have each statement handle(hstmt) for each of them? or one statement handle for several SQL query statements?

for example,

```
lstrcpy((LPTSTR)update, L"insert into employee values  ('Dshong','summer','LosAngeles');");
SQLExecDirect(hstmt1, update, SQL_NTS);

lstrcpy((LPTSTR)update, L"insert into works values ('Dshong','Small Bank',    2500);");
SQLExecDirect(hstmt3, update1, SQL_NTS);

lstrcpy((LPTSTR)select, L"select * from works;");
if (SQLExecDirect(hstmt, select, SQL_NTS) != SQL_SUCCESS)
    return printf("can’t exec direct");


lstrcpy((LPTSTR)select1, L"select * from employee;");
if (SQLExecDirect(hstmt2, select1, SQL_NTS) != SQL_SUCCESS)
    return printf("can’t exec direct");
```

should I give like this for two insert statements and two select statements with four hstmt?

and if I give like this,

```
lstrcpy((LPTSTR)insert, L"insert into employee values ('Dshong','summer','LosAngeles');");
SQLExecDirect(hstmt1, insert, SQL_NTS);
```

the SQLExecDirect has hstmt1 as parameter but I don`t know how SQLExecDirect works with it..

And as I think, the result should be one line inserted, isnt it?

but when I run the code, it inserts multi-same rows for `('Dshong','summer','LosAngeles')`...
when I printed out the result, `('Dshong','summer','LosAngeles')` was inserted multiple times 
even though the insert line was not in the for loop or so...

and how they work together with the functions below?

- `SQLBindCol(hstmt, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, id, (SDWORD)sizeof(id), &idlen);`
- `SQLFetch(hstmt)`

I know what they simply doing but.. here I want to know exactly in which way 
hstmt ( statement handle) work with them..

thank you..
:)

Answer (score 5):

A handle in C is just a pointer to a chunk of memory that's allocated by ODBC.  Typically a struct that keeps track of the state of a SQL query.  You don't have much use for the handle in an INSERT statement, you use it just once.  Unless it fails, then you need to pass the *exact* same handle to SQLError() to find out what went wrong.  Which ODBC then uses to access that internal struct and retrieve the error code.  The advantage of a handle over a struct pointer is that it hides the internal implementation.

You certainly need to use it repeatedly for a SELECT query since you want to retrieve the query result.  You must pass the *exact* same handle to SQLBindCol() to map a column in the query result to a memory location.  And to SQLFetch() to retrieve a row.

If you know C++ then it can be helpful to think of a handle as the *this* object pointer.  And SQLAllocStmt() as the constructor.  And SQLFetch() as an instance method of the class.  And finally SQLFreeHandle() as the destructor.    Which is exactly what a C++ ODBC wrapper class does, like MFC's CRecordSet, CDatabase to wrap a SQLHDBC handle.

In most cases you only use a single SQLHSTMT handle.  Unless you run multiple SQL statements at the same time.  Say to generate UPDATE statements from a SELECT query, that requires two handles.