# What is "sth" with respect to web traffic

Tags: linux, shell, wireshark, web-traffic

Just wondering if anyone could enlighten me to what **sth** might be. (Seen in *Tranalyzer* flow files.) Basically it's a web analysis category (ip address, port, **sth**, etc) but I'm not sure what meant by it and there is no mention in the documentation.

(Also for bonus points what would a value of dir mean for **sth**?)

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: +1 for the question. I though of that today, thanks to ask =)

Comment: I had a colleague ask and I didn't know either, so thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sth** means : **ST**atement **H**andle

The connection to a database.

See http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/connect_to_db.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/13208866/465183

**Edit** :

In perl, if I display the content of the object using `Data::Dumper` with a [DBI](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI)  script :

```
$VAR1 = bless( {}, 'DBI::st' );
```

but that's not very helpful. It's means only that's a `DBI::st` object.

Comment: Is't it STatement Handle?

Comment: haha, seems it can be left to the imagination which t is in the abbreviation.